# How do I store a Java KeyStore password?

Tags: java, keystore, private-key

In my web application I access a private key that is stored in a Java KeyStore. I would like to know what is the best/recommended way to store the password for the KeyStore and private key.

I've considered using a properties file but that does not seem very secure for use in a production environment (storing password in a plain text file). Also, hard-coding the password in my code is not an option I'm willing to entertain.

Thanks.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

You could use a properties file as you mentions just hash the password for extra security salt hash the password. This gets round the issue of having to keep a password in plain text. You can then either use MD5 or SHA1 password to hash it, personal choice.

Comment: If you hash the password, how will you retrieve the password? It makes no sense to hash the password.

Comment: You don't retrieve it you hash it again and check they are the same. For example if i have the hash of your username: d3a03c197da2c09307f06f8513443599 
Then in the application you would hash what the user put in so your username to see if it was the same.

Comment: I have to agree with Καrτhικ, you won't be able to open the key store with the hash of its password. Protecting the key store with a hash of a password does not add any extra security.

Comment: This answer just makes no sense for the question being asked. Why is this accepted? :/

Comment: If you hash the password, then you have to store the hashkey in memory too.. then you're right back at the problem described in the question

Comment: you can't use the password hash if you do not implement the authentication algorithm as well (or if 3rd party service do not support this option)

Answer (score 10):

This is a tricky bootstrapping problem. Some options:

- Have your app prompt the user to unlock the keystore (not very friendly, but possible)
- Store the password in an owner read only file (0400 ) and use that to unlock the keystore.  The attacker has to break into your server to read the file. This seems to be the most widely used technique
- Use an HSM
- Using something like Hashicorp Vault (but it also has the bootstrapping issue as well).

Comment: Is there any improvement since 2016 in this area, I guess not so. This simply says the JKS access should be restricted by system access rights, but we all looking for any platform independent solution.
Bullet 1 is not solution for service applications.